# Reading multiline user's input

Tags: haskell, io

I want to lazily read user input and do something with it line by line. But if user ends a line with `,` (comma) followed by any number of spaces (including zero), I want give him opportunity to finish his input on the next line.

And here is what I've got:

```
import System.IO
import Data.Char

chop :: String -> [String]
chop = f . map (++ "\n") . lines
    where f [] = []
          f [x] = [x]
          f (x : y : xs) = if (p . tr) x
                           then f ((x ++ y) : xs)
                           else x : f (y : xs)
          p x = (not . null) x && ((== ',') . last) x
          tr xs | all isSpace xs = ""
          tr (x : xs) = x :tr xs

main :: IO ()
main =
    do putStrLn "Welcome to hell, version 0.1.3!"
       putPrompt
       mapM_ process . takeWhile (/= "quit\n") . chop =<< getContents
       where process str = putStr str >> putPrompt
             putPrompt = putStr ">>> " >> hFlush stdout
```

Sorry, it doesn't work at all. Bloody mess.

*P.S. I want to preserve `\n` characters on end of every chunk. Currently I add them manually with `map (++ "\n")` after `lines`.*

Comment: A bit of help: one way to check if a string ends with a comma followed by whitespace would be `("," `isPrefixOf`) . dropWhile isSpace . reverse`.

Comment: I am not sure lazy IO is the right tool for interacting with the user through a prompt. I'd switch to strict IO. Still, this could be a nice exercise.

Comment: @chi, yeah, exercise of pain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about changing the type of `chop` a little:

```
readMultiLine :: IO [String]
readMultiLine = do
              ln <- getLine
              if (endswith (rstrip ln) ",") then
                liftM (ln:) readMultiLine
              else
                return [ln]
```

Now you know that if the last list is not empty, then the user didn't finish typing (the last input ended with `','`).

Of course, either `import Data.String.Utils`, or write your own. Could be as simple as:

```
endswith xs ys = (length xs >= length ys)
                 && (and $ zipWith (==) (reverse xs) (reverse ys))
rstrip = reverse . dropWhile isSpace . reverse
```

But I missed the point at first. Here's the actual thing.

```
unfoldM :: (Monad m) => (a -> Maybe (m b, m a)) -> a -> m [b]
unfoldM f z = case f z of
            Nothing -> return []
            Just (x, y) -> liftM2 (:) x $ y >>= unfoldM f

main = unfoldM (\x -> if (x == ["quit"]) then Nothing
                      else Just (print x, readMultiLine)) =<< readMultiLine
```

The reason is, you need to be able to insert the "action" to be done on input between reading one multi-line input and the next. Here `print x` is the action inserted between two `readMultiLine`

---

Since you have questions about `getContents`, let me add. Even though `getContents` provides a lazy `String`, its effectful changes to the world are ordered with the subsequent effects of processing the list. But the processing of the list attempts to insert effects between effects of reading particular list items. To do that, you need a function that exposes the chain of effects, so you can insert your own effects between them.

Comment: I mapped `map head` over your `chop` to actually use it in the program. Have you tried it? Result: input never ends...

Comment: @Mark sorry, I did miss the point at first and thought the mess was with parsing input. Now I updated it with the `unfoldM` function.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Although this solution works, it deviates from my original design too much. You're using custom function `readMultiLine` instead of pure transformation of `getContents` output. I expected that the whole solution would be a clever implementation of `crop`. Perhaps your approach is better, I will examine it in detail, later.

Comment: @Mark I think you will discover that you cannot modify `IO a` returned by `getContents`, because the algebraic structure of `IO` is not exposed. (eg if `Monad` was some other construct with known structure, like a list, then you can modify it)

Comment: I don't want to modify IO, I want to split its result into strings. It is absolutely possible. For example I can use `map (++ "\n") . lines` and it works just fine. I think it is possible to involve more complex algorithm so that input string is split only by `'\n'` not preceding by `','`.

Comment: @Mark like I said, it is absolutely possible with list, because its structure is exposed through `(:)`. You absolutely can insert something between arbitrary items in the list, because the structure of the list is known. It is not so for `IO`. When `getContents` provides you with a `String`, it doesn't provide you with distinct chain of effectful changes to the world, which you could manipulate and insert your own effectful changes strictly between two readlines.

Comment: @Mark: for complex reasons (namely, that `mapM` can be defined with applicative functors rather than monads), it is physically impossible for different lines in the `mapM_` call to affect each other; `mapM_` can only sequence the order that they happen but cannot choose different actions based on the last line. So when you try to do what you're doing, probably what will happen is the program will wait for *all* input before trying to do *anything*, which is not what you want. You **need** something like `readMultiLine` to make the next line's parse depend on the last one; `mapM` is not enough.

Comment: @ChrisDrost, it's not that 'different lines in the `mapM_` affect each other', `mapM_` called *after* splitting, and it processes different chunks independently. This story is not about `mapM_`. Problem is in splitting that takes place before any processing. Now tell me, what is principal difference between function `lines` that does its job perfectly, and another function `crop`, that **just uses different logic of processing the same lazy string of input**? I can use `lines`, `words`, but I can't write proper `crop` (yet).

Comment: You're right, I think. I've added an answer which may help.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using `pipes`, preserving the laziness of the user's input

```
import Data.Char (isSpace)
import Pipes
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as Pipes

endsWithComma :: String -> Bool
endsWithComma str =
    case (dropWhile isSpace $ reverse str) of
        ',':_ -> True
        _     -> False

finish :: Monad m => Pipe String String m ()
finish = do
    str <- await
    yield str
    if endsWithComma str
        then do
            str' <- await
            yield str'
        else finish

user :: Producer String IO ()
user = Pipes.stdinLn >-> finish
```

You can then hook up the `user` `Producer` to any downstream `Consumer`.  For example, to echo the stream back out you can write:

```
main = runEffect (user >-> Pipes.stdoutLn)
```

To learn more about `pipes` you can read [the tutorial](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.1.3/docs/Pipes-Tutorial.html).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I wrote something wrong in a comment and I thought that now that I understood what you were trying to do, I'd give an answer with a little more substance. The core idea is that you're going to need a state buffer while you loop through the string, as far as I can tell. You have `f :: [String] -> [String]` but you'll need an extra string of buffer before you can solve this puzzle.

So let me assume an answer which looks like:

```
chop = joinCommas "" . map (++ "\n") . lines
```

Then the structure of `joinCommas` is going to look like:

```
import Data.List (isSuffixOf)

 -- override with however you want to handle the ",\n" between lines.
joinLines = (++)

incomplete = isSuffixOf ",\n"

joinCommas :: String -> [String] -> [String]
joinCommas prefix (line : rest)
    | incomplete prefix = joinCommas (joinLines prefix line) rest
    | otherwise = prefix : joinCommas line rest
joinCommas prefix [] 
    | incomplete prefix = error "Incomplete input"
    | otherwise = [prefix]
```

The `prefix` stores up lines until it doesn't end with `",\n"` at which point it emits the prefix and continues with the rest of the lines. On EOF we process the last line unless that line is incomplete.